# Xcode 8 app runs on device unit test crashes with __abort_with_payload

Tags: ios, xcode8, xctest

I have a project with two targets, an app, and UI Tests for that app. I can run the app on my device. When I try to run a test on my devices, it immediately crashes with `__abort_with_payload` on Thread 1 and absolutely no other clue as to what is going wrong. Oddly, I have been able to run this test on other devices.

How can I get my tests running on my device?

Comment: Not sure, but doing a simple Google gives some hint that it could have to do with certificate/signing (?) the error code doesn't give much information tho.

Comment: @Sneak sure, and if I weren't able to run my app normally I'd at least have a clue what to do. I am letting Xcode manage the signing on both targets. I'll look more deeply at the profile settings. Would be nice if Apple could throw a more helpful message.

Comment: I agree, the errors are very hard to handle, not much information mostly. Have you tried to run it in the simulator? Do you get the same crashes there?

Comment: @Sneak Test works on the simulator. Presuming there's a signing or entitlement issue with the real device and the test target.

Comment: Very hard to guess what it could be since the error can be several different things, atleast now you have a clue if it works on the simulator. maybe try search and see every possible solutions to different causes for example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40886484/app-crash-on-device-but-works-on-simulator-ios there are many more if you google your error log. GL